# How OCaml match works?

Tags: ocaml

```
(* Data type definitions *)
type t =
  | True
  | False
  | If of t * t * t
  | Zero
  | Succ of t
  | Pred of t
  | IsZero of t

let rec isNumber t =
  match t with 
    Zero -> true 
  | Succ t1 -> isNumber t1 
  | _ -> false
```

When we call `isNumber` give pattern `(Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))`, how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `t` type is recursive. As you've seen, it can be constructed with `Succ` which takes another value of type `t`, which could itself be constructed with `Succ`, and so on.

The `isNumber` function is likewise recursive. If it finds the `Succ t1` pattern, it calls `isNumber` on `t1`.

For your sample value of `Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))` it looks like:

```
isNumber (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))
isNumber (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))
isNumber (Succ (Succ Zero))
isNumber (Succ Zero)
isNumber Zero
true
```